How can i deserialize the data from this raydium liquidity pool in rust?
Can someone help me deserialize the data in this raydium liquidity pool, i think it's a standard one. "AgFnRLUScRD2E4nWQxW73hdbSN7eKEUb2jHX7tx9YTYc"
I dont find the PoolState to deserialize it.
